# Split address street name house number and room number

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, explode

I need split address: `Main Str. 202-52` into
`street=Main Str.` 
`house No.=202`
`room No.=52`
I tried to use this:

```
$data['address'] = "Main Str. 202-52";
$data['street'] = explode(" ", $data['address']);
$data['building'] = explode("-", $data['street'][0]);
```

It is working when street name one word. How split address where street name have several words.
I tried `$data['street'] = preg_split('/[0-9]/', $data['address']);`But getting only street name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regular expression like

```
/^(.*)\s(\d+)\W+(\d+)$/
```

if you need all up to the last whitespace into group 1, the next digits into Group 2 and the last digits into Group 3. `\W+` matches 1+ chars other than word chars, so it matches `-` and more. If you have a `-` there, just use the hyphen instead of `\W+`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1hZe6/1) and a [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/zZQ8Lv):

```
$s = "Main Str. 202-52";
if (preg_match('~^(.*)\s(\d+)\W+(\d+)$~', $s, $m)) {
    echo $m[1] . "\n"; // Main Str. 
    echo $m[2] . "\n"; // 202
    echo $m[3];        // 52
}
```

Pattern details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last....
- `\s`  - whitespace, followed with...
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\W+` - 1+ non-word chars
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `$` -  end of string.

Also, note that in case the last part can be optional, wrap the `\W+(\d+)` with an optional capturing group (i.e. `(?:...)?`, `(?:\W+(\d+))?`).

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew... you are genius. Thank you. Yes regex good decision.

Comment: I little bit edited regex to the `'/^(.*)\s(\d+)(?:\W+(\d+))?$/'` now without errors... i need use your optional suggestion.